# Adding HealthKit entitlement to your app ID - No device

Tags: ios, healthkit

I just started learning ios development/swift so I apologise in advance if this may sound like a dumb question.
I am trying to integrate healthkit in my app by following some tutorials. All of them say to go to xcode capabilities first and enable healthkit.
My problem is this doesn't work. I get an error for Add the "HealthKit" entitlement to your app ID - No device.
Any tip/idea what I should do?

Also I have a developer account but I haven't purchased any membership (if this has smth to do)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to enroll in the developer program.

> If you’re new to development on Apple Platforms, you can get started with our tools and resources for free. If you’re ready to **build more advanced capabilities and distribute your apps on the App Store, enroll in the Apple Developer Program**. The cost is 99 USD per membership year.

[Enrollment image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBCRS.png)

Comment: Incorrect answer. You do not need to enroll in the Apple Developer Program to utilize HealthKit. Certain capabilities, such as Apple Pay, would need the Apple Developer Program, but for HealthKit an Apple ID should suffice. 

More here:  https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/

Answer (score 4):

I just enable automatically manage signing of Xcode and solve my problem. [image]

Here is my health kit capability

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Entitlements confer specific capabilities or security permissions to your iOS or OS X app.

You need to generate a Certificate and a Provisioning Profile to have your entitlement. This you can generate from developer.apple.com but you will need a Membership to do so.